# Integrate Dreamweaver with Git on OS X

Tags: git, dreamweaver

I'm in the process of adopting Git with my company, however some of the designers use Dreamweaver for composition and layout.

Dreamweaver includes a tool for SVN, but I've been trying to find a way for them to include git so they can visually commit and push their changes to the repository.

Googling, I've found [GitWeaver](http://github.com/ChrisMcKee/gitweaver) but it seems to be, of all things for a Git tool, Windows-exclusive.

So, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 2):

[Gitti](http://www.gittiapp.com/) is also a pretty good, but in beta at the moment. It seems to be very intuitive and easy to work with.